# VPN Connection to Windows Network behind Firewall

Tags: vpn, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, pfsense, windows-firewall

We have a Windows network with a single Windows Server 2012 server which works domain server as well as a file server, which is protected by pfSense firewall.

We want to allow a specific user (with company-owned laptop joined to the domain) to connect to our LAN (mainly the file server) from home.

Can anyone suggest where to start? Either to use the Windows Server as VPN Server or setup something on the pfSense system to accept incoming connections?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use Bitvise, an SSH Client and Server System to do exactly that. It allows Remote Desktop to the Windows Server, and I find is a little more integrated and security focused than other solutions e.g. putty, MobaXterm for example.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend setting up an Openvpn Server in Pfsense and use it to connect to the Company network from outside. The steps are well documented and the setup works pretty well. The major advantage is, you don't need to open anything from your internal net to outside or no need to make any change there. Make sure the VPN client gets assigned the internal DNS after connecting. Then it can access all the local resources without any problem.

Here is the official documentation to "Configuring an OpenVPN Remote Access Server":
https://www.netgate.com/docs/pfsense/vpn/openvpn/openvpn-remote-access-server.html

Comment: Thanks. I can't upvote because I am new in here, but this is something I can work on. Meanwhile, I successfully implemented PPTP with help of simple port forwarding but then I realized that it is not considered secure anymore. Thanks a lot once again.